# React Native project, index.ios.js or index.android.js not generated

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I started with React-Native today. And I am following a web tutorial.

Did all the installations correctly on my Windows machine:

- Java Jdk
- Android Studio
- Node/NPM
- Yarn

then installed react-native

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

finally a hello world project

```
react-native init albums
```

I am not getting any errors. My app runs (basically loads up) on my Android phone perfectly.

The app.js is bit conditional on platform choice:

```
 /**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' +
    'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android: 'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});

export default class App extends Component<{}> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To get started, edit App.js
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          {instructions}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
```

I just want to know if this is normal to not get those files generated.
Shall I create those 2 index files? Or the latest react-native does not need 2 separate files? (The tutorial I am following is of Jan 2017)

[image: The Project structure]

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This is a new feature added to react-native. The new project template now doesn't contain two separate files. You can still create and use like before if you prefer but its just normal to use it as it is. Its just a preference and the requirement of your project. You can find more info about the change on [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/6e99e314b232c315628c31f97a865c17c071ad23).

*From the commit notes*

> This change (initially discussed in
>   [react-community/create-react-native-app#26](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/26)) moves the HelloWorld
>   project template from two nearly identical entry points
>   (`index.android.js` and `index.ios.js`) to a single, minimal
>   `index.js` entry point. The root component is created in `App.js`.
>   This unifies the project structure between `react-native init` and
>   Create React Native App and allows CRNA's eject to use the entry point
>   from the HelloWorld template without any hacks to customize it. Also
>   examples in the docs can be just copy-pasted to `App.js` the same way
>   in both HelloWorld and CRNA apps without having to first learn about 
>   `AppRegistry.registerComponent`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply because the new project template now doesn't contain index.android.js and index.ios.js separately. It now only contains a one minimal  index.js entry point.

> If you want to do something specific for both/one of the platforms
>   then you can create your own index.android.js and index.ios.js files
>   and then just import the code in both of them from index.js file and
>   do the necessary changes there.

index.android.js and index.ios.js can be written as:

```
import Render from './App';

export default Render;
```