# React Native how to add index.android.js manually?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I am new to React Native, I'm following a video tutorial for beginners. I'm developing on windows 10 and using React Native version 0.49.1 . In the tutorial I'm following there are two index files: index.android.js & index.ios.js.
As I understand those file are untied now to index.js file,
I got it from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46591682/react-native-project-index-ios-js-or-index-android-js-not-generated) that was asked.
Nevertheless, I still want to work with two separate index files, but I don't know how to do so - do I have to delete App.js file and index.js files?
And if so, what should be the content of index.android.js & ios files?
I would appreciate an explanation or a quick guide on how to do it.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: did you create your new project with `react-native init` or `create-react-native-app` command?

Comment: I used react-native init

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For projects created with `react-native init`, an `index.js` file is still generated, and looks something like this initially:

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('YourProjectName', () => App);
```

Manually adding `App.ios.js` and `App.android.js` in the same directory will allow you to include unique code for each platform, as it follows the pattern for [platform-specific extensions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/platform-specific-code.html#platform-specific-extensions). However, it won't be enough to have either one or the other. You need to include both otherwise the code splitting won't take effect (and will default to whatever is present in `App.js`).

So to answer your question, yes you need to delete `App.js` and replace it with `android.App.js` and `ios.App.js`. Then restart the React Native packager terminal window for your simulator or device to detect the change.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I'm going to try it out and update later :)