# React native beginner index.android.js is not showing

Tags: android, react-native, sublimetext

There is no code. I am creating a project but some files are missing.

Using command `react-native init helloworld` project is created, but `index.android.js` and `index.ios.js` aren't generated or missing, only `index.js` is appearing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native project, index.ios.js or index.android.js not generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46591682/react-native-project-index-ios-js-or-index-android-js-not-generated)

Answer (score 13):

This is due to a recent [update](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.49.0).

> New projects have a single entry-point (index.js) from now on ([6e99e31](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/6e99e314b232c315628c31f97a865c17c071ad23)) - @fson

This shouldn't cause you any trouble during the compilation or run-time.

Comment: and one problem is after installed in my phone. it is showing  could not connect to developement server and many thing in red screen . please helpe me.

Comment: Have you tried to read this ?

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/next/docs/running-on-device.html

Comment: Dev Settings → Debug server host for device and add my ip address. but still red box is open.

Comment: but it is run on my simulator perfectly .please if you have any idea

Answer (score 4):

You can try out this:

```
npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. I build a scratch app. After finding solution on many help portals, I finally find file. Its `app.js` not `index.js`. In app.js you can find ios and android files.

You can find more info [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14386)

And if you want to use these files then downgrade your react version. Yeap, downgraded to 0.44.0 and works now. In cause somebody doesn't know how to downgrade react, you need to install: [react-native-git-upgrade](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/react-native-git-upgrade)

Answer (score 0):

New react native apps are created with a single index file, therefore we officially support single index file.

Ref link:- https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/3040