# React Native latest upgraded version issues (app directory)

Tags: react-native

I am a beginner at React Native and have begun to take some time off to work on my new app project.  I have noticed that there is a lot of difference with RN old and the new version. One is the combination index.js and App.js instead of index.android.js & index.ios.js.

The other is the new folder structure after react-native init-ios/android is completely changed. Following the standard installation guidelines and creating RN project, I do not see App directory created at all (the only folders are *tests*, android, iOS, node_modules.

Have you seen this after the latest upgrade? How do I rectify this?  Any suggestions will be great.

Comment: possible duplicate of this [React Native project, index.ios.js or index.android.js not generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46591682/react-native-project-index-ios-js-or-index-android-js-not-generated) and this [React native beginner index.android.js is not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46685380/react-native-beginner-index-android-js-is-not-showing)

Answer (score 0):

Create your own app directory, put all your logic in there. 
Import the root file into `App.js` in root folder.

`$ react-native run-android` or $ react-native run-ios` and app should run as expected.

You can use create-reactive-app with expo if don't wish to use the react-native-cli. See react-native docs, getting started for more information.